# Mass Search and Replace with Wildcards or Reg Expression MyString.Length to Len(MyString)

Tags: regex, vb.net, notepad++, replace

I have a large ASP.NET project where I want to do a mass search and replace (about 3500 instances)

I want to change

```
If strErrorMessage.Length > 0

If strSomeString.Length > 0

If strWhatever.Length > 0
```

and any other similar call to the Length method from a string to the following

```
If Len(strErrorMessage) > 0

If Len(strSomeString) > 0

If Len(strWhatever) > 0
```

Anyway to reliably do this in one shot?

I can do a search and replace for something like

```
If *.Length > 0 --> If Len(*) > 0
```

This just won't work though as it won't understand how to rearrange it properly.  Currently have VS2010 and N++ at my disposal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually I would expect to see people wanting to go from `Len()` to `.Length` to get away from the VB6 approach. Going in the reverse direction sounds questionable and seems like a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Visual Studio Find/Replace (with the regex options enabled) you can use this:

**Find what:** `If {:a+}\.Length \> 0`

**Replace with:** `If Len(\1) \> 0`

Pattern explanation:

- `:a+` = the `:a` matches an alphanumeric char, and the `+` matches at least one occurrence
- `{}` in `{:a+}` = Visual Studio regex's way of "tagging" (i.e., capturing) an expression
- `\>` = the `>` must be escaped with a backslash since it's a metacharacter in this regex flavor.
- `\1` = refers to the text matched in the tagged expression. The number `1` refers to the first (and only, in this case) tagged expression.

You can read more about the MSDN regex reference for Find/Replace [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293063(VS.71).aspx).

As I had mentioned in my comment, I think using `Len()` is a step backwards and ties your code down to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace. [@drventure brought up a good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937724/mass-search-and-replace-with-wildcards-or-reg-expression-mystring-length-to-lenm/3937780#3937780) though, since calling `.Length` on a null value would throw an exception. Instead of checking the length you could use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx). In .NET 4.0 you can also use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).

Instead of `If strErrorMessage.Length > 0` you can use:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strErrorMessage) Then
' or '
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strErrorMessage) Then
```

If you're interested in using this you can keep the original "Find what" pattern and change the "Replace with" pattern to this: `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(\1)`

Comment: There's really no such thing as "tying your code down to the VisualBasic namespace". That dll is part of the .net framework core and isn't likely to be going anywhere anytime soon. Plus there's plenty of examples of C# code making use of functions within that namespace to simplify various pieces of functionality.

Comment: That said, Ahmed's point about String.IsNullOrEmpty is still a good one. It's effectively the same thing as Len(x) = 0, even though it's always bugged me as being awfully wordy. Of course, a nice little extension method on the string class could take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

About Ahmed's comment. The likely reason here is that the *length* method is an *instance* method and as such, if invoked on a string variable that is null, will error.

LEN on the other hand, is more like an extension method and will simply return a 0 whether the string is null or a string that contains no chars. Len works much more like *len* should work in my opinion.

But back to the question.

Have you checked out

http://rxfind.codeplex.com/

A regex command line search and replace tool. That should make quick work of that job.

Comment: +1 good response about `Len()` versus `.Length`. Thanks for pointing that out.